# Can we use "from", "to", "than" interchangeably in this structure "different (from/to/than somebody/something)"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

see this structure:

**different (from/to/than somebody/something)**: not the same as somebody/something; not like somebody/something else. Ex: "*American English is significantly different from British English.*" [Source](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/different?q=different)

So, can we say:

*American English is significantly different to British English.*

or

*American English is significantly different than British English.*

They sound pretty weird to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> American English is significantly different to British English.

The use of the preposition "to" after "different" is common in informal writing or spoken English in BE. It's not used in AE.

> American English is significantly different than British English.

The use of "than" is chiefly used in AE; it's not common in BE.

> American English is significantly different from British English.

The use of "from" is very common in both AE and BE.

Comment: Having a mother and two aunts who were teachers, they would all be spinning in their graves if I used anything other than "different from". We are/were all native BrE speakers and it grates that other (IMHO incorrect) usages have been accepted even by the BBC.