# Your explanation is different from/to my knowledge of the policy

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

The case is, Someone explain something to me, but such explanation is not the same as I was told before. For example, there's a policy in the company and someone explain to me how it works, but I was told by another person before about the same policy, and what they said are different.

Can I say "Your explanation is different from/to my knowledge of the policy."? I prefer to use the word "knowledge" in this case.

Thanks very much!

Comment: I don't think ***differ | difference | different*** is really the right term here, because "explanations" and "knowledge" are different *kinds* of things anyway, regardless of whether they're compatible or not. Consider instead something like *Your explanation **conflicts with** my knowledge of the policy*.

Comment: If what you're asking about is the choice of preposition *(different **to / from**)*, that should be covered by earlier [Can we use “from”, “to”, “than” interchangeably in this structure “different {from/to/than somebody/something}”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/76369/can-we-use-from-to-than-interchangeably-in-this-structure-different-fr)

Answer (score 1):

"Different from" would be preferred, but "different to" is also possible.

Instead of "knowledge", you should use "understanding".  Your knowledge of the policy is the factual aspect. You might know the policy, meaning that you can quote it without looking. Or you might understand the policy, meaning that you know the meaning and intention of policy.

Comment: Thank you so much James, your answer helps me a lot! Do you mean "understanding" is better in this case and "knowledge" is also OK? and "Your explanation is different from/to my knowledge of the policy." sounds like a native expression?

Answer (score 0):

His knowledge is good. John's is better. Mine is **different than** theirs. Answer: It depends on context. [all this is about the policy in question].

So, your explanation of the policy is different than mine.

Your explanation is funny. His explanation is serious. Mine is different than yours.